# jQuery validate plugin is not working in MVC form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-validate

I have a MVC form like this

```
<head>    
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="get" id="login">
            <input id="email" class="text required email" type="text">
            <input type="submit" value="Login...">
        </form>
        <script>
            $(function () {
               $("#login").validate()
            });
        </script>
    </body>
```

but for some reason when i click on the submit button the jquery validate is not working and i get an error like this

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function

**but when i use the same html in a normal html page** along with the link to the same script, **i am able to validate the textbox**. am i missing something in MVC should i have to enable/disable any properties in MVC.
What am i doing wrong, please help.
Thank you

Comment: Make sure you have loaded the relevant jQuery validate library

Comment: @Shyju as i mentioned, i use the exact plugin for both html as well as cshtml page. i get error in cshtml and not in html page. do i have to enable  some options in mvc, should i change anything in mvc view's web.config....
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

really my mistake !!!
when i used inspect element, i found there is two jquery plugin which was being loaded and when i narrow down the cause it was me who was unknowingly loading another jquery plugin in the _ViewStart.cshtml page.
thought to share this, so somebody else could save the day.
Thank you
@Shyju thanks for your help